# How to trim leading and trailing white spaces of a string?

Tags: go

Which is the effective way to trim the leading and trailing white spaces of string variable in Go?

Comment: The online documentation describes exactly what's going on and has runnable and editable examples!

Answer (score 348, accepted):

#### strings.TrimSpace(s)

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := "\t Hello, World\n "
    fmt.Printf("%d %q\n", len(s), s)
    t := strings.TrimSpace(s)
    fmt.Printf("%d %q\n", len(t), t)
}
```

Output:

```
16 "\t Hello, World\n "
12 "Hello, World"
```

Comment: Try "\t Hello,\nWorld\n " not work :( ... how remove newline?

Comment: It still trims the beginning and end but it won't remove the newline in the middle because that's not what trimming does. You'd have to use strings.Replace or something similar to remove the newline in the middle of the string.

Answer (score 42):

There's a bunch of functions to trim strings in go.

See them there : [Trim](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Trim)

Here's an example, adapted from the documentation, removing leading and trailing white spaces :

```
fmt.Printf("[%q]", strings.Trim(" Achtung  ", " "))
```

Comment: How to trim \t\n?
```fmt.Printf("%q", strings.Trim("\t\t\t\t", `! \t`))``` It is not working

Comment: @aokaddaoc have you tried `strings.TrimSpace(str)`?

Answer (score 10):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(strings.TrimSpace(" \t\n Hello, Gophers \n\t\r\n"))
}
```

> Output:
>       Hello, Gophers

And simply follow this link - https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimSpace

Comment: Repost of [the accepted answer from a few years prior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22688229/6243352). Please consider upvoting that answer rather than reposting it so the thread isn't flooded with redundant information. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

For trimming your string, Go's "strings" package have `TrimSpace()`, `Trim()` function that trims leading and trailing spaces.

Check the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Trim) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

@peterSO has correct answer. I am adding more examples here:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    strings "strings"
)

func main() { 
    test := "\t pdftk 2.0.2  \n"
    result := strings.TrimSpace(test)
    fmt.Printf("Length of %q is %d\n", test, len(test))
    fmt.Printf("Length of %q is %d\n\n", result, len(result))

    test = "\n\r pdftk 2.0.2 \n\r"
    result = strings.TrimSpace(test)
    fmt.Printf("Length of %q is %d\n", test, len(test))
    fmt.Printf("Length of %q is %d\n\n", result, len(result))

    test = "\n\r\n\r pdftk 2.0.2 \n\r\n\r"
    result = strings.TrimSpace(test)
    fmt.Printf("Length of %q is %d\n", test, len(test))
    fmt.Printf("Length of %q is %d\n\n", result, len(result))

    test = "\r pdftk 2.0.2 \r"
    result = strings.TrimSpace(test)
    fmt.Printf("Length of %q is %d\n", test, len(test))
    fmt.Printf("Length of %q is %d\n\n", result, len(result))   
}
```

You can find this in [Go lang playground](https://play.golang.org/p/RFrQCSEiIFi) too.

Answer (score 0):

A quick string **"GOTCHA"** with JSON Unmarshall which will add wrapping quotes to strings.

*(**example:** the string value of `{"first_name":" I have whitespace "}` will convert to `"\" I have whitespace \""`)*

Before you can trim anything, you'll need to remove the extra quotes first:

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/8qbn0MV-FBr)

```
// ScrubString is a string that might contain whitespace that needs scrubbing.
type ScrubString string

// UnmarshalJSON scrubs out whitespace from a valid json string, if any.
func (s *ScrubString) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    ns := string(data)
    // Make sure we don't have a blank string of "\"\"".
    if len(ns) > 2 && ns[0] != '"' && ns[len(ns)] != '"' {
        *s = ""
        return nil
    }
    // Remove the added wrapping quotes.
    ns, err := strconv.Unquote(ns)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // We can now trim the whitespace.
    *s = ScrubString(strings.TrimSpace(ns))

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in performance, so I did a comparison of just trimming the left
side:

```
package main

import (
   "strings"
   "testing"
)

var s = strings.Repeat("A", 63) + "B"

func BenchmarkTrimLeftFunc(b *testing.B) {
   for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
      _ = strings.TrimLeftFunc(s, func(r rune) bool {
         return r == 'A'
      })
   }
}

func BenchmarkIndexFunc(b *testing.B) {
   for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
      i := strings.IndexFunc(s, func(r rune) bool {
         return r != 'A'
      })
      _ = s[i]
   }
}

func BenchmarkTrimLeft(b *testing.B) {
   for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
      _ = strings.TrimLeft(s, "A")
   }
}
```

`TrimLeftFunc` and `IndexFunc` are the same, with `TrimLeft` being slower:

```
BenchmarkTrimLeftFunc-12        10325200               116.0 ns/op
BenchmarkIndexFunc-12           10344336               116.6 ns/op
BenchmarkTrimLeft-12             6485059               183.6 ns/op
```

Answer (score -1):

Just as @Kabeer  has mentioned, you can use TrimSpace and here is an example from golang documentation:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(strings.TrimSpace(" \t\n Hello, Gophers \n\t\r\n"))
}
```

Comment: Repost of [the accepted answer from a few years prior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22688229/6243352). Please consider upvoting that answer rather than reposting it so the thread isn't flooded with redundant information. Thanks.

Comment: You are right - apologies on this