# Remove space between specific string

Tags: go

I need to remove whitespace between `</Listing>` and `<Listing>` inside a file.

I looked here:

[How to trim leading and trailing white spaces of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688010/how-to-trim-leading-and-trailing-white-spaces-of-a-string/22688229)

But that is not string specific.

Comment: You could try using regexp: https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're munging nested/structured data like XML I'd strongly suggest using a real XML parser.

But just using a regexp it isn't too hard:

```
r := regexp.MustCompile(`(?m:</Listing>\s*<Listing>)`)
var s string = "</Listing><Listing>"
fmt.Println(r.ReplaceAllString("</Listing>  \n\n <Listing>", s))
```

Note the `?m` regexp flag to enabled multi-line matching (assuming you want to allow `</Listing>` and `<Listing>` to be on separate lines